# Why is psql inserting a tilde when I press any of the keys in the Home key cluster?

Tags: postgresql, keymapping, tilde

I'm using **psql 8.2.3** on FreeBSD.  Every time I press **Insert**, **Home**, **Delete**, **End**, **Page Up** or **Page Down**, a tilde (`~`) character is inserted instead of performing the expected function of the key.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [Endlessdeath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542186/why-is-psql-inserting-a-tilde-when-i-press-any-of-the-keys-in-the-home-key-cluste/542350#542350), this turned out to be a key mapping problem with the operating system (**FreeBSD**), *not* **psql**.  You can make these keys work as expected by creating or adding to a configuration file for `inputrc`.

You can create a file named `.inputrc` in your home directory with the following:

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
```

Alternatively, you can create a global file for all users.  A common practice for this is to create or add to the file at `/usr/local/etc/inputrc` the same lines as above and then export the variable in `/etc/profile`:

```
export INPUTRC=/usr/local/etc/inputrc
```

Ensure that `/etc/profile` is sourced by your shell (most do by default) and you're good to go.  Note that the file won't be sourced until you log out and in again.

Here are some other resources for this problem:

- http://bsdpants.blogspot.com/2007/08/make-home-and-end-keys-work.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-how-to-customized-home-del-insert-keys-for-bash-shell.html
- http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a psql problem - it's os specific.
A [quick search on google](http://fixunix.com/bsd/538417-home-end-delete-page-up-down-keys-not-working.html) could help.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't even realize it but now I see that the same behavior occurs on the command line also.